# Using 'GET' to display selected options in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am learning flask. I wanted to start off my creating a simple form selection page. My intention is have the user select the option and then display it in another page using `GET`.
I am trying the following code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def search():

    return render_template('select_doc.html')

@app.route('/view_doc/<k>')
def view_doc(k):
    return render_template('view_doc.html',k=k)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my select_doc.html

```
{% block content %}

<body>
    <h1>Pick your plag</h1>
        <form action='/view_doc'>


                <select name="k">
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
<input type='submit' value='Select'>
</form>
</body>
{% endblock content %}
</html>
```

This is my view_doc.html

```
<html>
    {% block content %}
    <body>
      <br>{{ k }}<br>
    </body>
        {% endblock content %}
        </html>
```

However, I get an error saying `404 not found`.
This is my run.py. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your form `action` attribute should match the route specified in the decorator of function `view_doc` so `/results`...etc. Try that then we check what else is wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that, changed it now. But am still getting the 404 not found

Comment: Your route requires `<k>` parameter but it's not sent by the form. When you hit submit with `method="get"` which is the default for form, the request url will be `/results?k=value`. So you either remove `<k>` from your route and extract it from the querystring, or you write some js to put the value on the url like this `/results/value`. The easiest option is the first one, so you can just do `request.args.get('k')` to extract `k` and use it in `render_template`.

Comment: @fips Got it thanks, Why don't you answer this question formally?

Comment: if we are done guessing and it's an answer that works, i will! did that solve your problem?

Comment: yes it did. thanks a lot

Comment: cool! answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route requires `<k>` parameter but it's not sent by the form. When you hit submit with form `method="get"` (default when not specified), the request url will be `/results?k=value`.

So you either remove `<k>` from your route and extract it from the querystring, or you write some js to put the value on the url like this `/results/value`. The easiest option is the first one, so you can just do `request.args.get('k')` to extract `k` and use it in `render_template`.

Answer (score 0):

You need angular brackets in view_doc

```
@app.route('/view_doc/<k>')
def view_doc(k):
    return render_template('view_doc.html',k=k)
```

You should also tidy your code a little so it is more readable.

Comment: see comment from fips above, I've edited the code fragment to match.

Comment: I'm afraid that I am getting the same error despite all the changes